# how many null bytes, concatenating strings in C

Tags: c, string, malloc, strcat

If i want to concatenate 2 strings in C, do i have to allocate an extra null char for every string or one is enough?

```
int main(){
    char *s1 = NULL;
    char *s2 = NULL;
    char *s1_s2 = NULL;

    s1 = malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen("string1") + 1);
    strcpy(s1, "string1");
    s2 = malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen("string2") + 1);
    strcpy(s2, "string2");

    s1_s2 = malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(s1) + strlen(s2)) + 2); // shouldn't it be only 1 null char ?
    strcpy(s1_s2, s1);
    strcat(s1_s2, s2);
}
```

in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1383649/concatenating-strings-in-c-which-method-is-more-efficient) question, they use 2 null bytes for each string. Can some one shed some light?
Thanks

Comment: All strings only needs one extra byte, since there is only one string terminator. The same goes for `s1_s2` in your example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only one is needed.

In the question you linked, they are actually also adding an extra space character which requires an extra byte.

Answer (score 3):

No, you don't need two extra null bytes.

In memory, your strings will look like:

```
s1 -> 's' 't' 'r' 'i' 'n' 'g' '1' '\0'

s2 -> 's' 't' 'r' 'i' 'n' 'g' '2' '\0'

s1_s2 -> 's' 't' 'r' 'i' 'n' 'g' '1' 's' 't' 'r' 'i' 'n' 'g' '2' '\0'
```

Answer (score 1):

The final string should end with a null byte so one is enough.

Edit:
The question you sent, there's a space between the two strings.

```
strcpy(both, first);
strcat(both, " ");
strcat(both, second);
```

Answer (score 1):

Only one is needed. You always need just one null character at the end of the string, which here happens to be a concatenation of two strings.

Answer (score 1):

In the question that you linked to, a space is put between the strings that are concatenated together. An extra `char` must be allocated for this space.

In your example, you do not put a space between the strings, so only one additional `char` is needed.