# concatenating strings in a printf statement

Tags: c, printf

I am compiling with:

```
gcc 4.7.2
c89
```

I have the macro:

```
#define LOG_ERR(fmt, ...)                                               \
    fprintf(stderr, "[ERROR] %s:%d: error [%s] " fmt "\n", __func__, __LINE__, strerror(errno), ##__VA_ARGS__)
```

And I am using it like this:

```
LOG_ERR("Failed to connect to message queue [ %d ]", msg_id);
```

The `fmt` has been concatenated in the `fprintf` statement. How is this possible?

I tried to do the same with the following below (just to test the concept), but failed with a compile error:

```
/* Using char array */
const char name[] = "Joe";

printf("Hello how " name " how are you today?\n");

Using constant string literal
const char *name = "Joe";

printf("Hello how " name " how are you today?\n");
```

Both gave me the following error:

```
expected ')' before name
```

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1383649/concatenating-strings-in-c-which-method-is-more-efficient

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When it fails, it's because you're using variables. String literals can be concatenated by the compiler i.e. if you write "abc" "123" then the compiler will treat this as "abc123". And when you do this in the macro, the preprocessor means that this is exactly what is sent to the compiler

```
LOG_ERR("Failed to connect to message queue [ %d ]", msg_id);
```

becomes

```
fprintf(stderr, "[ERROR] %s:%d: error [%s] " "Failed to connect to message queue [ %d ]" "\n", myfunction, 123, strerror(errno), msg_id);
```

Might be worth checking out the stringizer and concatenation macros too (for the preprocessor - `#` and `##` and I never remember which is which...)

  Andrew

Answer (score 6):

You need a format specifier, check out the [documentation for printf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/)

```
const char *name = "Joe"; // or your char array, either's fine

printf("Hello how %s how are you today?\n", name);
```

Your attempt:

```
printf("Hello how " name " how are you today?\n");
```

Looks a little more C++ish

```
cout << "Hello how " << name << "are you today?\n";
```

Answer (score 4):

Difference is that the macro is textually replacing the word `fmt` with your string.  Putting two or more literal strings together gets you the concatenation of those strings.

```
"Hello " "World" "!!"
/* is the same as */
"Hello World!!"
```

Remember, only **literal** strings will do this.  This **does not** work for variables.

Think of macros like a find/replace in your code.  To illustrate, consider your macro definition -

```
#define LOG_ERR(fmt, ...)  \
    fprintf(stderr, "[ERROR] %s:%d: error [%s] " fmt "\n",
            __func__, __LINE__, strerror(errno), ##__VA_ARGS__)
```

When you use it like this -

```
LOG_ERR("Failed to connect to message queue [ %d ]", msg_id);
```

It does a textual replacement and becomes -

```
fprintf(stderr, "[ERROR] %s:%d: error [%s] " "Failed to connect to message queue [ %d ]" "\n",
            __func__, __LINE__, strerror(errno), msg_id)
```

The side-by-side strings and concatenated and voila -

```
fprintf(stderr, "[ERROR] %s:%d: error [%s] Failed to connect to message queue [ %d ]\n",
            __func__, __LINE__, strerror(errno), msg_id)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to define a macro for `fprintf()` you may do like this which is simplest IMHO.

```
#define LOG_ERR(...)   fprintf(stderr, __VA_ARGS__)
```

and use it like

```
int main()
{

    int  myVar =100;

    LOG_ERR ("The value of myVar is %d", myVar); 

    return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <string>

#define MyPrint(...) {\
struct timeval tv;\
gettimeofday(&tv,0);\
printf("%d.%d:", (unsigned int)tv.tv_sec, (unsigned int)tv.tv_usec);\
printf(__VA_ARGS__);}
```

Comment: Please consider adding some explanation to your answer.

Comment: this idea is to add any additional actions before printf, any thing you want to be done before a printf. the demo code is to print date time and no enter sign in the end. the effect is when ever u printf, there is a timestamp ahead.