# Seg Fault when reading from file, and using pthread_create

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, pthreads, file-read

Whenever I run my code I get through 4 iterations of reading the file and creating a pthread until it segfaults with ID 11.

The segfault is caused by my print ln:
    printf("%s %s\n", "Calling lab_manifes_alignment with package", *package);
But why does this cause a segfault?

Halp?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

pthread_mutex_t mutex;

FILE *packageList;

void *submitPackage(void * packageReq){
    char ** package = packageReq;
    strcat(packageReq, " | sh lab_manifest_alignment.sh");
    printf("%s %s\n", "Calling lab_manifes_alignment with package", *package);
    system(packageReq);
    return NULL;
}


int main(){
    int numThreads;
    pthread_t threads[numThreads];

    //Init mutex
    if(pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, NULL)){
            fprintf(stderr, "Error initializing mutex");
    }

    int rc;
    FILE *packageList = fopen("package_list.txt", "r");
    if(packageList == NULL){
            fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: cannot open file.\n");
            return 1;
    }

    int i = 0;
    char line[128];

    while ( fgets ( line, sizeof line, packageList ) != NULL ){ 
    /* read a line spawn as many threads as needeed*/
        printf("%s %d, %s\n", "line: ",i, line);
        rc = pthread_create(&(threads[i]), NULL, submitPackage, line);

        if(rc){
            printf("ERROR: return code from pthread_create() is %d\n", rc);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        i++;
    }

    numThreads = i;

    for(i = 0; i < numThreads; i++){
            pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
    }

    fclose(packageList);
    return 0;
```

}

Comment: Are you intentionally causing concurrency problems?

Comment: That's kind of rude?  Sorry I haven't used pthreads in years......What are the issues if theres so many blatant problems?

Comment: No it is not rude. Concurrency is one of the problems. As I have asked before, is it intentional?

Comment: I have not introduced any intentional problems, I'm and amateur at C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pthread_t threads[numThreads];`   `numThreads` is uninitialized here, you should choose a maximum value of threads or allocate it dynamically.

`fgets ( line, sizeof line, packageList )` reads 128 bytes into `line` (the size of the array), but `strcat(packageReq, " | sh lab_manifest_alignment.sh");` adds something behind it. This is the reason for your segfault. You should increase the size of the array and decrease the size parameter in `fgets`.

The next iteration in your main thread overwrites your `line` array, while the threads working with it. You should use a 2D array or allocate a buffer in each iteration and free it in the thread after working with it. Each thread must get his own buffer, not everyone the same.

`char ** package = packageReq;` should be `char *package = packageReq;` and remove the `*` at the `printf`.

Comment: Note that my numThreads does get set to i, which is equal to the number of lines in my file.

After changing from using strcat to the first option here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1383649/concatenating-strings-in-c-which-method-is-more-efficient I got the seg fault to quit.

Thanks, I forgot to think that I would need a buffer for these lines..

Comment: I noted that, but during the declaration of the array its value is uninitialized andso it invokes undefined behaviour.

Comment: Ah..thanks..also..why the 2D buffer?  Couldn't I just make a 1D shared buffer, use a mutex, and have each line get push'd and popp'd from it?

Comment: sure, but since only 1 thread (including the main thread) can use the buffer at the same time, it would be like a single threaded program.

Comment: So I have gotten the buffer working...however  when I changed char ** package = packageReq; to char *package = packageReq; I now get the error: can't set (char *) to type (void **) --- using char ** package = &packageReq; is correct but still raises a warning...any info on how to eliminate this warning?

Answer (score 1):

I think problem in here:

```
char ** package = packageReq;
```

Try to change:

```
char ** package = &packageReq;
```